# How to implement partial class in different file for file scoped classes in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-7.0, c#-11.0

With [File scoped types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#file-scoped-types) in C# 11, It will not be possible to implement a partial class for a file scoped class in a different file.

Will this be an exception with the file-scoped classes? because it will lose the purpose of partial class in this way.

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/file

Comment: _"Will this be an exception with the file-scoped classes? because it will lose the purpose of partial class in this way."_ - won't it loose the purpose of file scoped classes the other way around?

Comment: @GuruStron I agree with you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With code generators you typically create a partial class in one file and ask the code generator to add functionality to this partial class in another file.

The code generator might want to create helper types in this other file to support the added functionality. The name given to this helper type could conflict with one of your types or types created by another code generator. This is where the `file` modifier is helpful.

This modifier is not meant to be applied to the partial class itself.

**MyClass.cs** (your code):

```cs
[GenerateHelpFunction] // Ask the code generator to add a method
public partial class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        var myText= new Text();
    }
}

file class Text // Your class
{
}
```

**MyClass.generated.cs** (added by source generator):

```cs
public partial class MyClass
{
    public void Help()
    {
        var sourceGeneratorsText = new Text();
        ...
    }
}

file class Text // Helper type created by code generator
{
}
```

Comment: Agree, so this way it would be forced not to implement the partial class outside the given file